# Decrease pdf-filesize in ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, imagemagick-convert

I am using GIMP to convert *grayscale PNM-files* (scanned documents) to PDF.
My goal is a small filesize. (Ideally: viewable on different devices    without any problems and maybe suitable long-term preservation - PDF/A?)

So far, so good. Trying to reproduce that process with ImageMagick in a batch script doesn't give me that same small filesize as in GIMP.

*GIMP (Ver. 2.8.14) workflow:*

1. Open File
2. Change resolution (density) to 300x300 Pixel/in
3. Set threshold to 127 (=50%)
4. Export as OutGIMP.pdf

*ImageMagick (Ver. 6.7.9-0 2012-09-16 Q16) workflow:*

```
convert Scan.pnm -density 300x300 -threshold 50% -monochrome OutA.pdf
convert Scan.pnm -density 300x300 -threshold 50% -monochrome OutB.png
convert OutB.png OutC.pdf
```

Using an [example File](http://workupload.com/file/M4CZKXF) this results in:

- OutGIMP.pdf: 141.195 Byte
- OutA.pdf: 684.245 Byte
- OutB.png: 137.246 Byte
- OutC.pdf: 217.860 Byte

How can I get a PDF with ImageMagick that is at least as small as the GIMP-PDF?

---

**Edit**

*Continuing the GIMP (Ver. 2.8.14) workflow from above with:*

5. Scale to 100x100 Pixel/in while keeping the Imagesize
6. Export as OutGIMP_100ppi.pdf

strangely results in:

- OutGIMP_100ppi.pdf: 179.123 Byte

Comment: @Stefan Hegny: Likely a typo, from the scripts OutB is a PNG.

Comment: IMHO "viewable on different devices without any problems and maybe suitable long-term preservation" is better achieved with PNG (an open standard) than with PDF.  Also, AFAIK Gimp's PDF are always 100PPPI so this may explain the smaller size.

Comment: @xenoid it was a typo, corrected it.
Exporting the image in GIMP as 100ppi results in a lower quality than 300ppi which you can clearly see. So GIMP seems not to reduce all PDFs to 110ppi. Strangely the PDF gets bigger in size.

Comment: the key, in my experience, is to reduce the "density" to about 150dpi, or even 72dpi, depending on the resolution of the source.